# Plotly - how to replicate the same histogram in a single plot

Tags: python, plotly

How to have this same graph on another row below?

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.1, scale=0.2, size=100)

trace0 = go.Histogram(
    x=x0
)
trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x1
)
data = [trace0, trace1]


layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack')
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.plot(fig, filename='stacked histogram')
```

I want to get from this, a single histogram in one plot:

[image]

To this result, two of the same histograms stacked in the same plot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found your question a big confusing (same plot three times), if what you want is an overlaid histogram plot as the title states, then I answered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Overlaid plots

Just replace `barmode = 'stack'` with `'overlay'`. I set opacity to 0.6 so that the two histograms are visible:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.1, scale=0.2, size=100)
trace0 = go.Histogram(
    x=x0,
    opacity=0.6
)
trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x1,
    opacity=0.6
)
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay')
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.plot(fig, filename='overlaid histogram')
```

This code returns the following plot:

[image]

#### Subplots

If what you want is repeat the same plot in a 2x1 grid, then you can achieve it in plotly using subplots:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from plotly import tools

x0 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.1, scale=0.2, size=100)
trace0 = go.Histogram(
    x=x0,
    opacity=0.6,
    name='trace 0',
    marker={'color':'#1f77b4'}
)
trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x1,
    opacity=0.6,
    name='trace 1',
    marker={'color':'#ff7f0e'}
)

fig2 = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles=('One', 'Two'))
fig2.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
fig2.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig2.append_trace(trace0, 2, 1)
fig2.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)

fig2.layout['barmode'] = 'overlay'
py.plot(fig2, filename='subplots')
```

You need to specify the names and colors to make sure that you'll get the same plot. And to get a stacked or overlaid histogram or whatever on each subplot, simply specify it in the figure's layout. For example, to get an overlaid histogram I did `fig2.layout['barmode'] = 'overlay'` above.

This will give you the following:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, possibly I didn't explain myself well. What I want is the same graph on two different rows

Comment: Ok, in this case you could resort to subplots, I edited the answer above.

Comment: It needs to be the same graph repeated twice. You just plot the two distributions separately. I need two overlay graphs on two rows.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you wanted a graph per trace...  I am editing the answer again. The issue with plotly is that the traces will be identified as different, so you'll get trace0,trace1 twice in the legend.